# A question to clarify the use of divergent series in calculating the casimir effect

Tags: regularization, casimir-effect

Some time ago I posted a [question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/19356/have-experiments-ever-suggested-two-different-values-to-the-same-divergent-serie) here on this forum. I would like to ask some questions regarding the way the energy per unit area between metallic plates is calculated. The full calculation is on [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Casimir_effect).

At some point in the calculation on the relevant wikipedia page (see the link above), we have the equation: $$\frac{ \langle E \rangle }{ A} = - \frac{ \hbar c \pi^2 }{6a^3}\cdot\zeta(-3)  . $$

In the next step, it is written rather casually that $\zeta(-3) = - \frac{1}{120} \qquad (*) $. This is true when considering the analytic continuation of the riemann zeta function or the Ramanujan Summation [method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramanujan_summation).

Therefore, it is concluded, that $$\frac{ \langle E \rangle }{A} = - \frac{ \hbar c \pi^2}{720  a^3} .  $$
I am wondering under which circumstances people decided to assume the $(*)$-marked equation is 'true'. I can think of a couple of scenarios:

1. The formula for $\frac{ \langle E \rangle }{A} $ was already derived by means of another method which did not require the use of (regularised) divergent sums. Therefore, physicists could infer that $\zeta(-3)$ *had* to be equal to $ - \frac{1}{120} $, making the derivation of the formula by means of this method, which does use divergent series, correct.
2. The exact formula for $\frac{ \langle E \rangle }{A} $ was not already known. Physicist did have some data points that roughly showed them how the formula should look. Therefore, they tried some different constants for $\zeta(-3)$. At some point they guessed $\zeta(-3) = - \frac{1}{120} $, which yielded a formula that coincided with the known data points. They might have already known that $\zeta(-3) = - \frac{1}{120} $ by means of zeta function regularisation, making it easier to use this equation as a "guess" to find a suitable formula for $\frac{ \langle E \rangle }{A} $ .
3. Some other scenario.

Which scenario roughly describes how the formula for $\frac{ \langle E \rangle }{A} $ came into existence? If it was scenario 1, which other method did physicists formerly employ to derive the formula? If it was scenario 3, how *did* this whole process unfold?

Thanks a lot,

Max

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/40822/2451 , http://math.stackexchange.com/a/39811/11127 , http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/26877/2451 and links therein.

Answer (score 1):

The zeta function is *defined* to be the (unique) analytic continuation of $\zeta(s):=\sum_{n=1}^\infty n^{-s}$. This implies $\zeta(-3)=1/120$.

Thus your (*) is true by definition and some theory that provides the formula
$\zeta(-n)=-B_{n+1}/(n+1)$ for natural numbers $n$.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_zeta_function

If the final result agrees with the (experimental or theoretical) tradition,
sloppy formal arguments like that in the Wikipedia article you cited are almost universally accepted in physics - except in mathematical physics, where the standards of rigors are much closer to those of mathematics itself.

Answer (score 0):

Your path of thoughts seems to me a little bit flawed. In the wikipedia-article (19.3.2014) ***before*** the formal reference to the $\zeta(-3)$ the formula was derived by some conceptual arguing which ended in a formula having the infinite sum-form $\sum |n|^{-3}$.  But this is only the formal description of the $\zeta(3)$.

So ***from*** some physical/logical arguing about an infinite number of standing-waves someone ***concluded*** the mathematical formula with the respective ***infinite number of terms*** which - "accidentally" - shows the form which is also that of the $\zeta()$-function.

Only after that he resorted to the equivalence, given in the mathematics of divergent series/Dirichlet-series, that this should be evaluated to $ \zeta(-3)= - \frac1{120}$ .

Why -in mathematics- this value is a good/reasonable evaluation for the $\zeta(-3)$ goes back to L.Euler and very easy arguments, for instance from the conversion of $1-8+27-64...$ (which can more easily be evaluated - with smoothing of partial sums, for instance by Euler-summation) to $1+8+27+64+...$ by his multiplication-trick and the resulting general $\eta()/\zeta()$-conversion.

Whether this purely mathematical rationale is then still reasonable in the real world of physics (and the casimir-effect and the assumption of infinitely many standing-waves) is another question and must be checked later. (I guess that the energy-formula with that value inserted has indeed already been checked to express correctly the matters which are concerned there, but I don't know that)