# Question about infinite sum in quantum field

Tags: quantum-field-theory, mathematical-physics, renormalization, regularization

I read from some books of number theory that $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^s} = -\frac{1}{12}\text{,when } s=-1.$$

Now is there such a result $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^s} = \pi \text{,when } s=1,$$or $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^s} =  c \pi \text{,when } s=1 \text{,where } c \text{ is a rational number ?}$$

I get a similar result in mathematics by analogue, I suspect the result may have some interpretation in physics.

Comment: Zeta function regularization $\zeta(-1)=-\frac{1}{12}$ is also discussed [here](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/3096/2451) and [here](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/19356/2451) and links therein, and on Math.SE [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/39802). Also related Phys.SE post [here](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/59931/2451).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The true fact is the following. Consider 
$$\zeta(s) := \sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} \frac{1}{n^s} \quad \mbox{with $s\in \mathbb C$ and } Re \:s >1\:. \tag{1}$$
That function, *with the said complex domain*, is well defined (the series absolutely and uniformly converges) and is a *complex analytic* function. As a consequence of a well-known theorem on analytic functions, it is possible to extend $\zeta$ outside its original domain into another complex analytic function with a larger domain. Generally speaking, this extension is *locally* unique.  With this extended definition and domain, (1) does not necessarily hold.

As a matter of fact, it is possible to prove that $\zeta$ admits a *unique* complex analytic extension on the whole complex plane $\mathbb C$ except the point $s=1$, where there is a singularity (a *simple pole*) which cannot be eliminated even assuming continuity only (which is a much weaker condition than analyticity).

Summing up, there is a unique complex analytic function $\zeta : \mathbb C \setminus \{1\} \to \mathbb C$ satisfying (1) in the open set $Re\:s >1$, it does not satisfy (1) in the rest of its domain, in particular $\zeta(1)$ cannot be defined.

Identities like 
$$\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} \frac{1}{n^s} = -\frac{1}{12}\quad \mbox{if $s=-1$}.$$
do not make sense in any cases, because the series in the LHS does not converge for $s=-1$ (evidently!). They make sense  referring to the analytic continuation of the originally defined function $\zeta$. In this precise sense, for instance when computing the determinant of unbounded operators with discrete spectrum, are useful in quantum (field) theory.

**ADDENDUM**. These properties of $\zeta$ are shared by other similar functions constructed out of the spectrum of some elliptic self-adjoint operator like $A:= -\Delta$, defined on a compact Riemannian manifold:
$$\zeta_A(s) := \sum_{\lambda \in \sigma(A)} (m_\lambda \lambda)^{-s}\:.\tag{2}$$
Above $m_\lambda$ is the geometric multiplicity of $\lambda$ which is always finite if $A= -\Delta$ also including  perturbations, in compact Riemannian manifolds.
Formally speaking, $\det A$ is proportional to the partition function of a QFT admitting the Lorentzian version of $A$ as operator of field equations, and when the Euclidean continuation of Lorentzian Killing time gives rise to compact orbits with period $\beta$ (the inverse temperature). The Killing time is the one used to define the static vacuum and the associated  thermal (KMS) states.  Formally
$$\det A = \prod_{\lambda\in \sigma (A)} m_\lambda \lambda\:.$$
However, that productoria generally diverges. Nevertheless the analytic continuation procedure works. Formally (I omit $m_\lambda$ for the shake of simplicity)
$$\zeta_A'(0) =  \frac{d}{ds}|_{s=0}\left(\sum_{\lambda \in \sigma(A)} \lambda^{-s}\right) = -\sum_{\lambda \in \sigma(A)} \ln \lambda = -\ln \prod_{\lambda\in \sigma (A)} \lambda\:.$$
Thus one can **define**
$$\det A := e^{-\zeta_A'(0)}\tag{3}\:,$$
provided $\zeta_A'(0)$ exist. In general it exists just in the sense of analytic continuation. I mean that the   function in (2) turns out to be well defined and analytic for $Re \:s > c_A$ for some real $c_A$ depending on $A$. Moreover that analytic function can uniquely analytically be extended on the whole  $\mathbb C$ except for a discrete set of points defining an extended complex  analytic function (actually meromorphic). That set does not include $s=0$. Therefore  definitions like (3) are safe, at least in principle.

This method can be generalized to compute more complicated objects like the *one-loop (thermal) renormalised stress energy tensor in curved spacetime* and, it is possible to prove that the procedure is equivalent to more popular ones like the so-called point-splitting method. (I spent part of my initial career dealing with these interesting topics.)

Answer (score 4):

Valter's answer is completely correct, but I'll just briefly expand on it to address the specific values you ask about. The place to go, really, is the Wikipedia page [Particular values of Riemann zeta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particular_values_of_Riemann_zeta_function), which lists mosts of the values of $\zeta(s)$ (which, as Valter explained, equals 
$$\zeta(s) := \sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} \frac{1}{n^s}$$
when $\operatorname{Re}(s)>1$) that can be expressed without the use of series, or using simpler ones.

For example, the value $\zeta(2)$ is well known to be $\pi^2/6$, and the other positive, even integers have zeta values which are rational multiples of a power of $\pi$.

On the other hand, the value $s=1$ is rather different, because the zeta function has a pole there. This means that there is no way to make the series
$$
\zeta(1) := \sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} \frac{1}{n}
$$
mean anything other than $\infty$. This series is of course the [harmonic series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_series_(mathematics)), which is probably the most famous example of a divergent series, and there are multiple simple proofs of why its value must be infinity.

However, if you ask why we insist that
$$1+\frac12+\frac13+\frac14+\cdots$$
is infinite, but we're OK with assigning a finite (and negative) value to
$$1+2+3+4+\cdots,$$
then I would say that the second series is just a handy way of expressing something else, and should not really have been used in the first place.